# linq to xsd (is it dead? has something replaced it?)

Tags: c#, xsd

I sometimes use type providers in F# to create typesafe 'queries' on xml data.
I'm looking for something that does something similar that can be used from C# (unfortunately F# has some magic that makes the types invisible to anything but the F# compiler).

There does seem to be this

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30747/LINQ-to-XSD

but this seems long dead?

There is xsd.exe, but it creates something quite clumsy compared to the 2 examples above (which seem quite similar).

Has Linq-to-xsd migrated somewhere else? or been superceded by something else?

Comment: A more modern and configurable alternative to xsd.exe is [XmlSchemaClassGenerator](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator)

Comment: https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore

Comment: @RobertHarvey - brilliant - thats the answer I think i wanted to see (well it would be nice for F# type providers to be accessible, but this is the next best thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @RobertHarvey's comment above - its his answer not mine

https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore